# mysql 5.5 server: undetermined results of an SELECT

Tags: mysql

I have a myisam table with 18 millions records in it.

```
   CREATE TABLE `AnyTable` (
  `OrderID` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `GroupID` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `TextID` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `Type` tinyint(3) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `EngineID` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `UpdateTime` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
  `data` longtext NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`OrderID`,`GroupID`,`Type`),
  KEY `EngineID-GroupID` (`EngineID`,`GroupID`),
  KEY `TextID-ContextType` (`TextID`,`ContextType`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

An I have a trouble with undermined select results:

```
for i in {1..100}; do date; mysql yabsdb -A -e "select EngineID, (GroupID|0), OrderID, Type, TextID, Data from AnyTable" | wc -l; sleep 5m; done

11553545
10795243
9855558
....
```

...while real rows count in table >18 millions

While indeed count of records in AnyTable grows constantly and monotonically. And its count is greater than 18 billions

No errors occured neither server nor client.

Why results of my select are so unpredictable?

First, I supposed there's a problem in libmysqlclient , but `insert into TmpTable select * from AnyTable` is  unpredictable too. So, it seems like the problem is inside a server.

Environment:

- ubuntu precise mysql 5.5
- lots of `insert ... on duplicate key update`
  request in this table.

Comment: Seems like you answered your own question: it has lots of writes into it, why do you expect same result for each select then?

Comment: Have you tried simply running the query in the mysql client?

Comment: Because there's no deletes from this table and it is  growing constantly and monotonically due these lots of inserts.

I expect results should grows constantly and monotonically too.

> Have you tried simply running the query in the mysql client? 

Yes I did.

Comment: Seems like a bug in mysql 5.5 in concurrent_insert=1 mode.

Comment: Workarounds:
1. set global concurrent_insert=0 
2. get READ lock on table before selecting from it: LOCK TABLES 'AnyTable' READ; SELECT...; UNLOCK TABLES;